Duplicate option in Laravel Blade select using select2-multiple class
I am using Laravel and have created a pre-selected item using Laravel Blade. However, the selected option is being duplicated, even though I only need it to appear once.
I used the class "select2-multiple". The selected option is being selected correctly, but two spans are being added instead of just one.

Here is the code I used:
<div class="tagging-wrapper">
    <select class="product-edit-tagging form-control select2-multiple " style="width: 100%;"
            name="tag_{{ $tagId }}[]"
            {{ $tag->is_unique ? ' ' : 'multiple' }}
            placeholder="{{ $tag->name . ($tag->is_mandatory ? ' *' : '') }}"
            @if($tag->is_mandatory) data-mandatory="{{ $tag->name }}" @endif
            id="tag_{{$tagId}}" data-tagging="{{$tagId}}">
        @if(!empty($tags[$tagId]))
            @if(config('modules.site.headline_activated'))
                @foreach ($tags[$tagId] as $child)
                    @if($child->is_headline)
                            <?php $showHeadline = 0; ?>
                            @foreach($tags[$tagId] as $headlineChild)
                                @if($headlineChild->headline_id == $child->id)
                                    <?php $showHeadline = 1; ?>
                                    @break
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            @if($showHeadline == 1)
                                <optgroup label="{{ $child->name }}">
                                    @foreach($tags[$tagId] as $headlineChild)
                                        @if($headlineChild->headline_id == $child->id)
                                            <option test1="test1" value="{{ $headlineChild->id }}"{{ in_array($headlineChild->id, $productTagIds) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }} data-additional-info="{{$headlineChild->id}}">{{ $headlineChild->name }}</option>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </optgroup>
                            @endif
                    @else
                        @if($child->headline_id == 0)
                        <option data-additional-info="test2" value="{{ $child->id }}"{{ in_array($child->id, $productTagIds) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }}>
                            {{ $child->name }}
                        </option>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @else
                @foreach ($tags[$tagId] as $child)
                    <option value="{{ $child->id }}"{{ in_array($child->id, $productTagIds) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }}>
                        {{ $child->name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endif
    </select>
</div>

In the script:
$(".select2-multiple").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 5
})


It would help if you post your code so that people can point the issue.

@Mr.Kenneth I have added code for how I print data in laravel blade and make it select which is pre-selected. in Script i added $(".select2-multiple").select2({
maximumSelectionLength: 5
})
